# Rails 3 - Calculate time in users timezone

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, time, timezone

I am creating a racing website for me and my friends.  When a user creates their account the choose their timezone from a select which I have populated with `ActiveSupport::TimeZone`.

When the user creates a race they can select the time and timezone that the race is taking place.  Example:

User has selected their timezone as Moscow which is -10 hours from UTC.  Another user then creates a race and selects the time 3pm in the afternoon in the timezone for Budapest, which is +3 hours from UTC.

I have trying to figure out how to calculate what the race time would be in Budapests timezone, but I am struggling, am I missing a simply way to do this?

Hope you know what I mean.

Eef

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store all times in UTC -- convert using ActiveSupport::Timezone.local_to_utc.

When showing a time, convert back to the local time for that user with ActiveSupport::Timzezone.utc_to_local.

```
= ActiveSupport::TimeZone.utc_to_local

(from gem activesupport-3.0.8)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  utc_to_local(time)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Adjust the given time to the simultaneous time in the time zone represented by
self. Returns a Time.utc() instance -- if you want an
ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone instance, use Time#in_time_zone() instead.
```